# Fetch List Using DTO projections using a Constructor Expression and JPQL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Perform a search on DisabScreenRequest and fetch  its child details also. Using DTO projections using a Constructor Expression and JPQL.

The parent entity with a child table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SCREEN_REQUEST")
public class DisabScreenRequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    private long requestId;

    @Column(name = "CIVILID")
    private Long civilId;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "_DISAB_SCREEN_REQ_DETAILS", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "REQUEST_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DISABILTY_TYPE_ID") })
    private Set<DisabMaster> disabilities = new HashSet<DisabMaster>();

    public DisabScreenRequest() {
    }

}
```

This is the disability table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DISAB_MASTER")
@Immutable 
public class DisabMaster implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="DIS_TYPE_ID")
    private long disabilityTypeId;

    @Column(name="DIS_TYPE_DESC")
    private String disTypeDesc;


    public DisabMaster() {
        super();
    }   

}
```

Had to fetch all the requests along with the disability for each request.

Search DTO(using this I had other joins to add other than one mentioned here).

```
public class RequestSearchDto {

    private long requestId;     

    private Long civilId;   

    private  Set<DisabMaster> disabilities;

    public RequestSearchDto() {
        super();
    }

    public RequestSearchDto(long requestId, Long civilId) {
        super();
        this.requestId = requestId;     
        this.civilId = civilId;     
    }

    public RequestSearchDto(long requestId, Long civilId, Set<DisabMaster>  disabilities) {
        super();
        this.requestId = requestId;     
        this.civilId = civilId;     
        this.disabilities = disabilities;
    }   


}
```

This is my JPQL query

```
public interface ReposJPQL {

    public String GET__REQUEST = "SELECT DISTINCT new org.test.RequestSearchDto "
            + "(dsr.requestId, dsr.civilId, dsr.disabilities)"
            + " FROM DisabScreenRequest dsr WHERE 1=1 ";


}
```

This will get an 
**org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet.**

What Iam I doing wrong here, how can I fetch the child table data  ?
Let me know if you need any info

Stack trace :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00936: missing expression

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:754)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:219)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:813)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1051)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:854)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1156)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3415)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3460)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
```

Comment: You should fully qualified class name with constructor expression. Something like com.xxx.yyy.RequestSearchDto.

Comment: That is using here mentioned class name only for readability. The error is related to fetching the list.

Comment: Can you share the entire stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: @Dherik 
select distinct disabsc0_.request_id as col_0_0_, disabsc0_.civilid as col_1_0_, . as col_2_0_ from _disab_screen_request disabsc0_ inner join _disab_screen_req_details disabiliti1_ on disabsc0_.request_id=disabiliti1_.request_id inner join _disab_master disabma2_ on disabiliti1_.disabilty_type_id=disabma2_.dis_type_id where 1=1 ... This is the query generated. there something wrong with the second parameter

Comment: @Dherik updated question with full stack trace

Comment: It's a Oracle error. Are you using the correct dialect database on Hibernate? Did you try to run this generated SQL directly on Oracle and see what happens?

Comment: @Dherik.. dialect is correct. I was able to fetch records with 2 values in constructor without the list.

Comment: Why there is where 1=1 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to fetch parent entity with a collection of its nested child entities you can use this simple approach using `@EntityGraph` annotation or JPQL with `join fetch`:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    //...
    @OneToMany
    private List<Child> children;
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    //...
}

interface ParentRepo extends JpaRepository<Parent, Integer> {

    // with @EntityGraph
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "children")
    @Override
    List<Parent> findAll(); 

    // or manually
    @Query("select distinct p from Parent p left join fetch p.children")
    List<Parent> findWithQuery(); 
}
```

Note to use `distinct` in your query to avoid duplicate records.

Example: [duplicate-parent-entities](https://github.com/Cepr0/duplicate-parent-entities)

More info: [DATAJPA-1299](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1299)

Comment: This answer must be accepted. Join Fetch gives too much control :)

Comment: I would say `left join fetch` will make more sense in this context as the there is no null constraint in the association.

Comment: Can i use **join fetch** clause in **DTO Projection** ?

Comment: @Arash You can use it If you don't have parents without children. Otherwise - they won't fall into the selection.

Comment: Thanks @Cepr0. You mean if i have Accommodation with Rooms and use DTO Projection with join fetch to fetch the Accommodation, it will contain the list of Rooms?

Comment: @Arash I meant that if you have some parents without any children, then such parents don't be present in the selection. 'Fetch join' is translated to such a SQL query: `select p.*, c.* from parents p join children c on c.parent_id = p.id` which selects only those parents which have been referenced from the `children` table. And doesn't select parents without children.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, you can't use constructor expression which take a `Collection`.

See the [JPA 2.2 Spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf), section 4.14 BNF, read about the constructor expression:

```
constructor_expression ::=
    NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}* )
constructor_item ::=
    single_valued_path_expression |
    scalar_expression |
    aggregate_expression |
    identification_variable
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model. Since the attribute name is used as default mapping, you mostly don't need explicit mappings as 80% of the use cases is to have DTOs that are a subset of the entity model.

A mapping for your model could look as simple as the following

```
@EntityView(DisabScreenRequest.class)
interface RequestSearchDto extends Serializable {
  @IdMapping
  long getRequestId();
  Long getCivilId();
  Set<DisabMaster> getDisabilities();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`RequestSearchDtodto = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, RequestSearchDto.class, id);`

But the Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.4/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-features