# Spring boot, execute custom query

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity

Im newbie to web development,and I did some examples like get data from mysql db and show them in a jsp pages.(use CRUDRepository )
but in that way we can only show only one table data.
what should we do if we want to show combine two table data.

### I found these while um searching,simply I m asking how we put a more complicated sql query to this.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u from User u where u.lastname like ?1%")
  List<User> findByAndSort(String lastname, Sort sort);

  @Query("select u.id, LENGTH(u.firstname) as fn_len from User u where u.lastname like ?1%")
  List<Object[]> findByAsArrayAndSort(String lastname, Sort sort);
}
```

---

if we can put that complicated query (like three tables or more) here,
should we create a new entity class according to query coloumns  ??
then again is that work because actually there isn't any table like that.

Comment: This is too broad. You need to learn JPA, associations, JPQL. Read the Hibernate doculentation, or a good book about it.

Comment: thanks very much. that "JPQL" hint really helped (lease I know where to look ).
And Sir if you can recommend anything more,appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get more complex data from DB you can use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections), for example:

```
public interface UserProjection {
    Long getId();
    Long getFirstNameLen();
}

@Query("select u.id as id, LENGTH(u.firstName) as firstNameLen from User u where u.lastname like ?1%")
List<UserProjection> getProjections(String lastName, Sort sort);
```

Note that you should use aliases in the query that must match with getters in the projection (`... as firstNameLen` -> `getFirstNameLen()`)

The same way you can get data from several (joined) entities.

If you have an entity with some associations, for example:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    //...
    @OneToMany
    private List<Role> roles;
}
```

then you can use repository method to get the users and their roles data even without any projection, just for the main entity (`User`). Then Spring does the rest of the work itself:

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "roles")
List<User> findByFirstNameContainingIgnoreCase(String firstName);
```

or the same with query:

```
@Query("select distinct u from User u left join fetch u.roles where upper(p.firstName) like concat('%', upper(?1), '%')")
List<User> findWithQuery(String firstName);
```

In this case all users will have their lists of roles are filled with data from the `roles` table.

(Note to use `distinct` in the query to prevent the result from duplicated records, more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51559856/5380322).)

---

Useful resources:

[Spring Data JPA - Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

- [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)
- [Repository query keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords)
- [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

[SpEL support in Spring Data JPA @Query definitions](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions)

[Hibernate ORM User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html)

- [Associations](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations)
- [HQL and JPQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql)

[JPQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html)

Comment: @is_sa91 you're welcome, but please don't forget to accept/upvote the answer if it helped you )

Comment: yeah.. sorry for that. :)