# Spring Boot - Apply a specific query to a database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have started with Spring Boot and I have the next doubt.

I am showing in screen all fields of a query to database but I would like to show only the registers on base the next query:

```
select * from user where remove = false
```

I only showing the method findAll for each class because this method working ok but I don't get to add a clause where.

This is my method to controller class (UserController.java):

```
@GetMapping
public List<User> findAll(){
    return userService.findAll();
}
```

This is my method to service class (UserService.java):

```
List<User> findAll();
```

This is my method in service implementation class (UserServiceImpl.java):

```
@Override
public List<User> findAll() {
    return repository.findAll();
}
```

This is my method to repository class (UserRepository.java):

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Integer> {

    // @Query("select * from user where remove = false")
    List<User> findAll();

}
```

I have tried to test in the class UserRepository the next annotation:

```
@Query("select * from user where remove = false")
```

But by the moment not working ok.

What is the best way to solve it ?, thanks

Comment: Have a look at `Table 2.3` on https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RC1/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `nativeQuery = true` in your query

```
@Query("select * from user where remove = false", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: This proposal works perfectly, I just had to change the syntax by: @Query (nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from user where remove = false")

Answer (score 1):

Use the query dsl instead native query:

```
List<User> findByRemoveFalse();
```

It works equal the native query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [repository query methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods), for example:

```
List<User> findByRemoveFalse();
```

I think my another answer will be also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51692712/5380322